# How to console log Index of current image in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, indexof, use-state

I have following code.

```
    function SolutionsSectionBoxItem({
     heading, //this information  I am getting from backend in parent component and passing here
     image,  //this information  I am getting from backend in parent component and passing here
     description,  //this information  I am getting from backend in parent component and passing here
     solutionLink,  //this information  I am getting from backend in parent component and passing here
    
    }) {
      const [bgImgIndex, setBgImgIndex] = useState(0);

      function handleEvent() {
       // ?????
      }
     return (
        <div
          className={styles["solutions-section-item-box"]}
          onMouseOver={handleEvent()}
        >
          <Link to={solutionLink}>
            <div className={styles["solutions-section-item-title"]}>{heading}</div>
            <img
              src={image}
              alt={description}
             className={styles["solutions-section-item-img"]}
            />
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default SolutionsSectionBoxItem;
```

now my question is how can I do following, when hover one of images I should get current image index and set in my state and alert or console log. I try something like:

```
      function handleEvent() {
      console.log(setBgImgIndex(bgImgIndex.indexOf(image)));
       }
```

But it not working, Please help me to resolve this problem, sorry that I cant give example of this code in codesandbox or in other code editor.

Comment: `onMouseOver={handleEvent()}` invokes the callback immediately upon render. What is `bgImgIndex` and what index would you be trying to reference? Is there an array of images being mapped somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to pass the node element target in your function but as Drew Reese says when you write `onMouseOver={handleEvent()}` it invokes directly your function when the component is mounted.

Here's a way to get some informations :

```
      function handleEvent(e) {
        console.log(e.taget.WHATYOUWANT)
      }
     return (
        <div
          className={styles["solutions-section-item-box"]}
          onMouseOver={(e) => handleEvent(e)}
        >
          <Link to={solutionLink}>
            <div className={styles["solutions-section-item-title"]}>{heading}</div>
            <img
              src={image}
              alt={description}
             className={styles["solutions-section-item-img"]}
            />
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
```

I assumed that your component is a return of a map function called by the parent and you just want to add style on mouse over so you can just do that way :

```
      const [isOnMouseOver, setIsOnMouseOver] = useState(false);

     return (
        <div
          className={styles["solutions-section-item-box"] isOnMouseOver && styles['Your class']}
          onMouseOver={() => setIsOnMouseOver(true)}
          onMouseOut={() => setIsOnMouseOver(false)}
        >
          <Link to={solutionLink}>
            <div className={styles["solutions-section-item-title"]}>{heading}</div>
            <img
              src={image}
              alt={description}
             className={styles["solutions-section-item-img"]}
            />
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
```